# Using Finance Services from Google Apps Script on an android app

Tags: google-apps-script

I was planning to create an android app (Paid) to show the stock quotes and other info by utilizing the "Finance Services" in "Google Apps Script" (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/finance/).

But I doubt whether it is legal to use this for a commercial application.

Does anyone else have any info on this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal or licensing terms.